# ¿Como pasar entradas a un proceso con OutputStream?

Tags: java

Hola buenas noches a todos

Tras estar un rato investigando y no encontrar nada sobre el tema, o tal vez que simplemente no sepa como buscar os vengo a formular una pregunta sobre un ejercicio que tengo en clase.

El ejercicio dice que debo generar un proceso hijo que reciba caracteres de entrada de la clase padre los pase a mayúscula y la clase padre tiene que sacar el resultado en pantalla.

Aquí posteo como tengo el proceso hijo (esta exportado como runnable jar).

```
public class Mayusculas {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader teclado = new BufferedReader (entrada);
    String cadena = teclado.readLine();

    System.out.println(cadena.toUpperCase());

}}
```

Bien, esta clase la tengo como jar, y la paso como argumentos a esta:

```
public class MayusculasPadre {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();

    InputStream out = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(out);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);


    String linea;
    linea=br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Linea:"+linea);
    br.close();

}}
```

El fallo es que no se pesar la entrada al proceso.

Alguien sabría como hacerlo?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tenía se ha solucionado.
Aquí dejo la solución por sí le vale a alguien.

```
public class MayusculasPadre {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.print("Introducir texto: ");
    //Método mejorado para introducción de caracteres por teclaro.
    String texto = utilidades.Entrada.cadena();

    //Ruta y argumentos para lanzar aplicación
    String arg1 = "java";
    String arg2 = "-jar";
    String arg3 = "C:\\Users\\Alumno\\Desktop\\mayusculas.jar";

    String[] param = { arg1, arg2, arg3 };
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(param).start();

    //Escribir en la escucha del proceso
    OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(osw);
    pw.print(texto);
    pw.close();

    //Caputrar la salida del proceso
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String linea = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Linea:" + linea);
    br.close();
}
```

Gracias a todos por el tiempo.